# Swift: Confused about AnyObject declaration

Tags: swift, type-alias, anyobject

I know AnyObject can be any class type, but what I'm confused about is the declaration of AnyObject, I have read a book and some articles saying it's a protocol, but when I looked at AnyObject declaration it shows me that it is a typealias AnyObject not a protocol, and if we supposed that typealias AnyObject is assigned to some protocols (Ex: typealias AnyObject = some protocols here) I can not see what protocols the typealias AnyObject is assigned to, please help.

Comment: What's the declaration you're talking about? Many people browse here on mobile and can't look this up for you.

Comment: did you read my post?

Comment: I sure did, but that doesn't change the fact that I can't see the declaration you're talking about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Formerly, `Swift.AnyObject` was an empty protocol defined in `Policy.swift` and known to the compiler. [On April 13, 2017, Slava Pestov changed it](https://github.com/apple/swift/commit/b5721e8d8e8bb6bb536e5e5a95717f20c5c24c2e#diff-d04f8572c34f7766393b64ea37a50bed) to the current `typealias` and removed knowledge of `Swift.AnyObject` from the compiler.

Currently, `Swift.AnyObject` is a `typealias`, [declared in `Policy.swift`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/d2e1f0916976583e6bba20cf550b9d9cfdb62612/stdlib/public/core/Policy.swift#L254) in the standard library source code:

> ```
> public typealias AnyObject = Builtin.AnyObject
> ```

`Builtin` is a special module that contains types and functions that are built in to the compiler. Members of the `Builtin` module don't have to be declared in Swift. Normal source code cannot access the `Builtin` module directly. The standard library is compiled in a special compiler mode that gives it access to the `Builtin` module.

The compiler deals with the `Builtin.AnyObject` type [in `swift::getBuiltinType` in `lib/AST/Builtins.cpp`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/d2e1f0916976583e6bba20cf550b9d9cfdb62612/lib/AST/Builtins.cpp#L118):

> ```
>   // AnyObject is the empty class-constrained existential.
>   if (Name == "AnyObject")
>     return CanType(
>       ProtocolCompositionType::get(Context, {},
>                                    /*HasExplicitAnyObject=*/true));
> ```

So `Builtin.AnyObject` is (somewhat paradoxically) a protocol composition containing no protocols as members (that's the `{}` argument), and flagged as being a reference type (that's the `true` argument).

What's a “protocol composition”? In Swift, you can declare that a variable's type is multiple protocols put together:

```
protocol P { }
protocol Q { }
var v: P & Q    // v's type is the composition of protocols P and Q
```

There is no way to write an empty protocol composition (a composition containing no protocols) in the Swift language.